# Tensorflow crash using tf.train.Saver() with GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm not even sure how to approach this problem, or what to search for, but I get an InvalidValueException thrown when I run some code on a GPU, when using a tf.train.Saver object to keep track of the variable state. When I comment out the Saver instantiation, or switch to CPU:0, then the code runs fine.

```
  File "entrypoint.py", line 496, in <module>
    online_mvrcca_multipie_test3()
  File "entrypoint.py", line 490, in online_mvrcca_multipie_test3
    gs_res = gridsearch_optimizer_cb(parameter_ranges,exp_f_handle);
  File "/homes/sj16/LPLUSS/deps/sjpy_utils/exptools/parameter_search.py", line 48, in gridsearch_optimizer_async
    f_handle(parameter_instance);
  File "entrypoint.py", line 487, in <lambda>
    {}\
  File "/homes/sj16/LPLUSS/deps/pyena/src/sessions.py", line 115, in submit_to_local_session
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'save/Const': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and devices:
Identity: CPU
Const: CPU
         [[Node: save/Const = Const[dtype=DT_STRING, value=Tensor<type: string shape: [] values: model>, _device="/device:GPU:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'save/Const', defined at:
  File "entrypoint.py", line 496, in <module>
    online_mvrcca_multipie_test3()
  File "entrypoint.py", line 490, in online_mvrcca_multipie_test3
    gs_res = gridsearch_optimizer_cb(parameter_ranges,exp_f_handle);
  File "/homes/sj16/LPLUSS/deps/sjpy_utils/exptools/parameter_search.py", line 48, in gridsearch_optimizer_async
    f_handle(parameter_instance);
  File "entrypoint.py", line 487, in <lambda>
    {}\
  File "/homes/sj16/LPLUSS/deps/pyena/src/sessions.py", line 115, in submit_to_local_session
    worker_result=worker_task(*worker_args);
  File "/homes/sj16/LPLUSS/src/experiments/matrix_reconstruction/online/mvrcca_online/image_exp/experiment_workers.py", line 41, in batch_mv_recon_test_mc7
    saver = tf.train.Saver()   #Here is the offending call to Saver(), having set up the graph
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 845, in __init__
    restore_sequentially=restore_sequentially)
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 504, in build
    filename_tensor = constant_op.constant("model")
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/constant_op.py", line 166, in constant
    attrs={"value": tensor_value, "dtype": dtype_value}, name=name).outputs[0]
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2260, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1230, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

I mean to me that looks like TF has no way to save a tf.constant to a checkpoint file if you're in GPU mode? Because there's no GPU implementation of a "kernel" (not sure what that means in this context) to execute the save/Const node (saving a constant?).

That would be a bit odd...the inability to save and restore a named constant...

Furthermore, I never use `tf.constant()`, but I'm guessing a Constant node is created when you call `tf.convert_to_tensor` with a numeric/numpy variable?

-----------Edit to show minimal example-----

Environment:

CUDA 7.5.18 w/ a Tesla K40c; Ubuntu 14.04; GPU Tensorflow 0.9.0rc0, using a python 2.7 miniconda environment

```
import os,math
import operator as op
import tensorflow as tf


with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    tf_session=tf.Session()

    exp_model_dir= os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"),'tf_scratchpad/saver_failure_dense_only')

    if not os.path.isdir(exp_model_dir):
        os.mkdir(exp_model_dir)

    ranklim=10
    dense_widths=[64,ranklim,64, 128]

    # input to the network

    input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1,128], name='input_data')

    current_input = input_data

    for layer_i, n_output in enumerate(dense_widths[0:]):

        n_input = int(current_input.get_shape()[1])
        W = tf.Variable(
            tf.random_uniform([n_input, n_output],
                              -1.0 / math.sqrt(n_input),
                              1.0 / math.sqrt(n_input)))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_output]))

        output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(current_input, W) + b)
        current_input = output

    # reconstruction through the network
    y = current_input
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - input_data))

    train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(os.path.join(exp_model_dir,'train'),
                                          tf_session.graph)


    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0075).minimize(cost)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    tf_session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

produces:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:924] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K40c
major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.745
pciBusID 0000:05:00.0
Total memory: 11.25GiB
Free memory: 11.15GiB
W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:572] creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0x2a95d80
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:924] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 1 with properties:
name: Quadro K600
major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8755
pciBusID 0000:04:00.0
Total memory: 1023.31MiB
Free memory: 425.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:59] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 0 to device ordinal 1
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:59] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 1 to device ordinal 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 1
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y N
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 1:   N Y
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:806] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:793] Ignoring gpu device (device: 1, name: Quadro K600, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0) with Cuda multiprocessor count: 1. The minimum required count is 8. You can adjust this requirement with the env var TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tfcrash.py", line 48, in <module>
    tf_session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'save/Const': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and devices:
Identity: CPU
Const: CPU
   [[Node: save/Const = Const[dtype=DT_STRING, value=Tensor<type: string shape: [] values: model>, _device="/device:GPU:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'save/Const', defined at:
  File "tfcrash.py", line 46, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 845, in __init__
    restore_sequentially=restore_sequentially)
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 504, in build
    filename_tensor = constant_op.constant("model")
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/constant_op.py", line 166, in constant
    attrs={"value": tensor_value, "dtype": dtype_value}, name=name).outputs[0]
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2260, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/homes/sj16/miniconda/envs/tensorflow27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1230, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

The error is actually thrown at initialize_all_variables(), but is blamed on the call to tf.train.Saver(). Commenting out the Saver() call, or using '/cpu:0' prevents the exception.

Comment: `Saver` only saves variables, but `Const` is a node. It's saved in GraphDef already, which is restored when you restore it with `import_graph_def`

Comment: Thanks for the response Yaroslav. Okie dokie.....so if I'm creating some simple Session object, then constructing my graph, and then calling tf.train.Saver(), how can I make it not crash?

I managed to gather that Saver only saves variables and the error says Const is a node, so I'm that far at least. And there's a thread somewhere mentioning import_graph_def for restoring graph structure. Buuut my code is crashing at the Saver instantiation, which is what I'm confused about. Do I need to tell it not to try and save the Const somehow?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting there, S.O won't let me edit it for 5 minutes or something...

Comment: If you are following instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/variables/index.html and it's crashing then it's probably a bug, a minimal example to reproduce the crash is then needed

Comment: Minimal example added, just a really simple dense autoencoder.

Comment: Just passing by to say that I face the same issue in my attempt to use the [officially provided resnet model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/resnet). I'm actually running Python 3 and TensorFlow 0.10.0, yet this error still occurs, both in the example in this question and the resnet model example. Was an issue ever raised in the project's issue tracker?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `tf.train.Saver()` should not come under `with tf.device('/gpu:0')`.

Every ops in TensorFlow has its assignment to device. and saver op should always be assigned to cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot assign a device to node `save/Const`: Could not satisfy explicit device specification `/device:GPU:0` because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.

You can move `saver = tf.train.Saver()` away from `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):`, theres ops will place on `/CPU:0`, and fix it.