# Problem with tf.train.Saver() and GPU - TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

My code is structured as follows:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
...
model = get_model(input_pl)
...
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
           ...
           for n in range(num_batches):
              ...
              sess.run(...)
           # eval epoch
        saver.save(sess, ...)
```

I want to save the model after the training phase. When I run it gives me this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation 'save/SaveV2': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:1' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
```

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173580/tensorflow-crash-using-tf-train-saver-with-gpu) I changed the code in this way:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
...
model = get_model(pointcloud_pl)
...
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
           ...
           for n in range(num_batches):
              ...
              sess.run(...)
           # eval epoch
        saver.save(sess, ...)
```

But now I get this error:

```
ValueError: No variables to save
```

I've tried also to do this way:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    ...
    with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        ...
            for n in range(num_batches):
               ...
               sess.run()
            # eval epoch
        saver.save(sess, ...)
```

And I still get the same error. The error is always in the `saver = tf.train.Saver()` line.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where do you build the graph? Can you add a comment in the code where the graph is built?

Comment: Edited the first code block. After `with tf.device():` and before `tf.Session()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved doing this:

1. `tf.Session()`
2. model
3. `saver = tf.train.Saver()`
4. `with tf.device():`

Here an example code

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ...
    model = get_model(input_pl)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    ...
    with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        ...
            for n in range(num_batches):
               ...
               sess.run()
            # eval epoch
        saver.save(sess, ...)
```